# How to change the Theme for Team Discussion in hierarchical manner?

Tags: development, visual-web-part, style.css

I need to show standard theme for the Team Discussion on my page. Is there any way to change the theme for Team Discussion Webpart?

Also Is there any place where I can get ready-made CSS and themes for the SharePoint webparts?

Comment: Can you please confirm that which SharePoint version you are using?

Comment: SharePoint 2010

Comment: I have shared some of the pre-made webparts in answer which can help you in customization

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few WebParts & Workarounds for Discussion board available online as mentioned below

[Sharepoint Discussion Rollup Web Part](http://www.amrein.com/apps/page.asp?Q=5824)

[Social Squared 2010](http://lightningtools.com/products/social-squared/)

[Microblog/Chat Web Part](http://www.amrein.com/apps/page.asp?Q=5810)

[Intranet discussion list with SharePoint 2013](http://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/2013/09/17/5-features-for-your-sharepoint-2013-intranet-homepage-aspx/)

Comment: Well! I Need only CSS Style to Team Discussion WebPart. Not custom or already built. Or better to customize out-of-box Team Discussion WebPart as per normal forum kind view

Comment: You can use the CSS from the above given webparts to customize your default Team Discussion.

Comment: Cannot use exact css and assets but helpful.